# Zip together all HTML files under current directory

Tags: linux, command-line

I am looking to zip together *.html files recursively under the current directory.

My current command is:

```
zip all-html-files.zip *.html
```

But this doesn't work recursively. Nor does adding the -r option it seems. Can anybody advise? I want to zip all html files under the current directory, including those underneath subdirectories, but zip the HTML files only, not their file folders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about this?

```
find /your/path/ -type f -name "*.html" | xargs zip all_html_files.zip
```

looks for all `.html` files under the directory `/your/path` (change it for yours). Then, pipes the result to `xargs`, which creates the zip file.

To junk the paths, add `-j` option:

```
find /your/path/ -type f -name "*.html" | xargs zip -j all_html_files.zip
```

Comment: As @devnull indicated in his question, you can add `-j` to junk the paths.

Comment: If the path has a space in it, xargs will pass it on as multiple arguments. Use `find ... | xargs -I {} zip all_html_files.zip "{}"`. I find the lack of a forced `-output-to-this-file` in `zip` a little dangerous since it's easy to get the args round the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" | xargs zip all-html-files
```

You can also say

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" | zip all-html-files -@
```

If you do not want to preserve the directory structure, specify the `-j` option:

```
find . -type f -name "*.html" | zip -j all-html-files -@
```

`man zip` says:

```
   -@ file lists.   If  a file list is specified as -@ [Not on MacOS], zip
   takes the list of input files from standard input instead of  from  the
   command line.  For example,

          zip -@ foo

   will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.

   Under  Unix,  this option can be used to powerful effect in conjunction
   with the find (1) command.  For example, to archive all  the  C  source
   files in the current directory and its subdirectories:

          find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@

   (note  that the pattern must be quoted to keep the shell from expanding
   it).

   -j
   --junk-paths
          Store just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do  not
          store  directory names. By default, zip will store the full path
          (relative to the current directory).
```

Comment: For some reason this zipped up the file folders too - Is there any way this script could ignore file folders and just zip up the files?

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "*.html" -print | zip all-html-files.zip -@
```